# node.js server giving error

Tags: javascript, tcp

personal hello have a server and he is giving a simple mistake but do not know how to solve and that the objects are apparently normal see the code below.

```
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

   var players = {}, count = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection',
    function (socket)
    {   
        var id = count++; //assign number
        var player = players[id] = new Player(id, 10, 1); //create new      player
    player.socket = socket;


    socket.on('chat',
        function (data)
        {
            var message = player.name + ': ' + data.message;
            socket.emit('chat', { message: message});
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat', { message: message});
        });

    socket.on('position',
        function (data)
        {
            player.x = data.playerX;
            player.y = data.playerY;
            player.z = data.z;


            socket.emit('position', {pid : player.id, playerX : player.x, playerY : player.y, z : player.z});
            socket.broadcast.emit('position', {pid : player.id, playerX : player.x, playerY : player.y, z : player.z});
        }); 

    socket.on('register',
        function (name)
        {
            player.name = name;
            player.registered = true;
            socket.emit('chat', { message : "Server: bem vindo ao server " + player.name + '!'});
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat', { message : "Server: bem vindo ao server " + player.name + '!'});

            for(var p in players)
            {
                //send initial update
                if(!players[p].disconnected)
                { 
                    socket.emit('addPlayer', {pid: players[p].id, x: players[p].x, y: players[p].y, name: players[p].name, sessionid: socket.id});
                    if(players[p].id != player.id)
                        players[p].socket.emit('addPlayer', {pid: player.id, x: player.x, y: player.y, name: player.name})
                }
            }

        });

    socket.on('disconnect',
        function (socket)
        {
            player.disconnected = true;
            delete players[player.id];
            player = null;
        });

});



 function Player(id, x, y, z) {
    this.id = id;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
    this.name = "";
    this.disconnected = false;
    this.registered = false;
    this.socket = null;
 }
```

Alloy normal server but when it will receive the data of the message

```
this.z = z;
```

"this.z = z is not defined"

Comment: new Player(id, 10) you're passing in only two parameters so y and z will be undefined

Comment: Also, the `Player` parameter is capital Z and `this.z` is looking for lowercase z.

Comment: That's right thank you, I had not seen that z was capitalized. now it worked.

Comment: Why don't you pass x,y,z parameters when calling `new Player(id, x, y, z)` ? From your snippet, you only passed id, x, y

Answer (score -1):

it might be due to the fact that your Player object needs to return `this` at the end of it.

Comment: I have to leave it:
  var player = players [id] = new Player (id, 10, 1);

Comment: yes but the bit at the bottom that says ```function Player``` doesn't return anything to create the object is what im trying to say

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher, the constructor only really needs `return this` if you plan on chaining the methods, otherwise no [as you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/penferx6/).